Can you use the interior product to calculate flux?
If I have a vector Field F and a 2D surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would $F \lrcorner dx \land dy \land dz= F_1 dy\land dz + F_2dz\land dx + F_3dx\land dy$
If this is the case, could one say that the interior product works similaly to the L-contraction from geometric agebra except that it "contracts" a vector with K-covector instead of "contracting" a vector and a K-vector?

The interior product and the geometric algebra contraction are essentially identical. The contraction is just the interior product modified with the musical isomorphisms so that it applies to multivectors. That aside, your formula is a correct application of the interior product.

Would it be correct to write $F \lrcorner dx \land dy \land dz = \langle F^ \flat , dx\land dy \land dz \rangle$ where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product for differential forms?

No, because that "inner product" is zero between differing grades. The interior product is instead the adjoint of the exterior product: for any multivectors $M, N$ and differential form $\omega$ $$\langle N, M\mathbin\lrcorner\omega\rangle = \langle M\wedge N, \omega\rangle.$$ This is using the natural pairing between multivectors and forms instead of your inner product, but you could just apply $\flat$ as you did if desired. Here you would take $M = F$, $\omega = dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$, and leave $N$ arbitrary.
